# Alertbox displays on seperate page rather than the same page.

Tags: php, html, css

I have used a alert box where once the data is added to the database it should pop up the alert box success message on the same page, but it displays on a different blank page rather than on same page. 
Here is my code:

```
<?php
    require("../connect.php");
    error_reporting(0);
    /*
    if(!(adminsessioncheck()))
    header('location:index.php'); */

    if(isset($_POST['add']))
    {
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];

if($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['cpassword']) {
     echo("Password did not match! Try again. ");
} 
else {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('','$username','$password')") or die(mysql_error());

    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.alert(""New user added."")</script>';

}

    }
?>


<form action="" method="post" >
     <table width="330" height="135" border="0" class="text">
<tr>
    <td><label>User Name</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" required></td> 
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><label>Password</label></td>
    <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><label>Confirm Password</label></td>
    <td><input type="password" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>

<tr><td></td><td align="center"><input type="submit" name="add" value="Add"></td></tr>
</table>
  </form>
```

Comment: __Warning SQL Injection___

Comment: I know that you can use an alert box with JavaScript. PHP will do a page refresh as it is running on server side not client side.

Comment: so how can i achieve that? any alternate method?

Answer (score 1):

this works please check , change the following line in your code

```
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">  window.onload = function(){
      alert("New user added");
    }</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('','$username','$password')") or die(mysql_error());
if($query)
{
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'alert("New user added.")';
echo '</script>';
}
else
{
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'alert("New user not added.")';
echo '</script>';
}
```

May this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

window.alert("New user added");

alert is always pop ups in the same window, So correct your syntax will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. The alert is coming on the same page. Chage the variables as per your requirements.

```
<?php
$password = 'hi';
$cpassword = 'hello';

if($password==$cpassword){
?>
     <script>
     alert('User Added');
     </script>
<?php
}else{
?>
     <script>
     alert('User not added');
     </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: there is a blank page before while alert

Comment: Could you share the whole code? May be there you have some code which is creating this page.